# How to find platform to invest in Canadian ETFs from overseas?

Tags: investing, canada, etf

I am intending to invest in Canadian ETFs. I reside overseas. Although I have Canadian SIN, I do not have a permanent address in Canada at the moment. I searched online for platforms which can allow investing from overseas. I found all the Canadian platforms ask for a Canadian address and phone number. For example, BMO investorLine, Wealthsimple and Questrade.

I searched for non-Canadian online platforms which offer international ETFs. But most of them direct me to American ETFs. I cannot seem to find a platform which allows me to invest in Canadian ETFs (I am particularly interested in FTSE Canada All Cap Index ETF (VCN), but can consider others). Is there a specific term I need to use when I search for such platforms?

Comment: Define *overseas*. In Europe there's this one: https://www.fondsweb.com/de/IE00B52SF786

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the term "expats" or "expatriates" in your search.

Comment: Thanks. It helped, and I found InteractiveBrokers